# Difference between using CreateView and forms.Modelform in creating a form for a django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

i have a Django model to store information of a Article , i saw to methods to create a form through which users can create a article and save it in the data base but i am not able to find what is the difference between two please help me with this?

1.This is the first method using ModelForm from django forms

...

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import Article

 class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Article
         fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content', 'reporter']
```

...

2.This is the second method using createview

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import Article

class ArticleForm(CreateView):
     model = Article
...  fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content', 'reporter']
```

what is the difference between using these two methods?

Answer (score 3):

`CreateView` is used for creating new objects and it handles most of the things on its own.

Django docs:

> A view that displays a form for creating an object, redisplaying the form with validation errors (if there are any) and saving the object.

You usually use `CreateView` for simple forms or when you have all the parts already made.

On the other hand, `ModelForm` is just a form based on a model that handles the basic validations which can be extracted from your model such as nullable, max length, data type and etc. But you need to handle the render, error displaying and even saving. You probably end up using a `ModelForm` if you have more complex validations and you need to reuse them.

Comment: I didn't understood the part that we need to handle render in case of using ModelForm , and still i am not clear when to use CreatView and when to use Model form.

Comment: `ModelForm` is a form than can be used anywhere. And it only can handle the form render. `CreatView` on the other hand is a view. It handles everything about a view. If you need a simple view to create an object, then you should use `CreatView`. If you need a form that can be used anywhere and you might need extra validations, then you should use `ModelForm`. View and Form are to separate concepts. You can read the docs for more details.